# Can the date a question was added as favourite be shown on the favourites list on the user profile?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, bookmarks, timestamps

I've really been enjoying the new notification for activity on favourite questions, but I'd like to see when I marked a question as a favourite, either in the favourite list on my profile, or as a tooltip over the favourite icon on the question itself:

[image]

Not fantastically important, but might help answer the question "what was I drinking when I made *that* a favourite...?"

Comment: Your image link appears to have died

Answer (score 3):

It's already saved for the *added* sorting, so it's just a Small Matter of Programming™.

Could definitely be interesting, even if not always useful.