# Show added date when sorting Favourites list by "added"

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, user-interface, bookmarks, timestamps

Here is a particular use case:

I've started to use the favourites, as suggested by [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310860/editing-without-bumping#comment1015694_310860), to save questions/posts as a reminder that they need editing:

> On the smaller sites you should rate limit yourself to, say, 1 per day. This requires some organisation, but the 'favorites' feature can be used for that.

"Why?", I hear you ask. Because, on any particular day, I've have probably already edited a number of questions and I don't want to flood the Active question list with my modified questions. So, I have been saving them up for a rainy day.

Today is such a day, and so, for the first time, when I opened the favourites list and sorted by *added*, I have just realised that I can't see *when* I added them, only the date of the last modification.

> [image: List of questions sorted by "added"]

Would it be possible to show the added date, as it would help me remember why I favourited a particular question. It is a shame that I can't make a private online note<sup>1</sup>, when I favourite a question, as to why I am favouriting it, so having a *date added* displayed would be the next best thing.

#### Note

I feel that this is different from [Can the date a question was added as favourite be shown on the favourites list on the user profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52302/can-the-date-a-question-was-added-as-favourite-be-shown-on-the-favourites-list-o) as I am asking for the date to be shown *only* when sorting on the *added* tab.

---

<sup>1</sup> This may become a future feature-request of mine.

Comment: FWIW, adding notes has been previously declined: [Adding a note to a favourite](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8619). I've made a [userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/6215/favourites-enhancer-tag-favourites-and-add-personal-notes) to add that feature if you're interested.

Comment: I am surprised this is not answered or addressed yet! I am also very curious about WHEN I starred/added a question as favourite.

Comment: @Vicent - The userscript in the comment above is *very* useful