# Allow users to view the exact date and time they followed a post

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, timestamps, follow-post

When I visit the ['Following' tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=following) on my profile, I can only see the date and time of the last activity but it doesn't show the date and time when I followed the post.

**Users should be able to see the exact time when they followed a given post?**

Arguments in favor of the feature request:

1. **Consistency:** Both following and voting<sup>1</sup> are anonymous. However, one can view the time of their vote but they currently can't view the time of their "follow".
2. This could be useful for tracking the actions taken on a post before/after following it. And more importantly, **detecting bugs**. I recently noticed an edit on a question that I follow. I don't remember seeing that edit at the time I followed the question and I never received a notification about it. Without knowing exactly when I followed the post, I can't be sure whether this is a bug or I just didn't notice the edit before following the post.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>This is true for both upvotes and downvotes. It's also true for close- and delete-votes (although they're considered flags internally, IIRC).</sub>

Comment: I'm pretty sure this info isn't available publicly, so better turn this question into a feature request asking to add that detail.

Comment: Following is considered a vote in the DB. For obvious reasons dates and times of votes aren't accessible publicly

Comment: I'm not sure if by "publicly" you mean "by other users" or "by anyone who isn't a dev", @Luuklag. Note that the dates and times of an _actual_ vote are in fact accessible by the user who voted. Anyway, I just turned this into a [feature-request] and added that as one of the arguments.

Comment: [A similar request for more-publicly Bookmarks (back then Favorites)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311941/show-added-date-when-sorting-favourites-list-by-added)