# Why did my not-so-recently-active questions receive many upvotes all of a sudden?

Tags: discussion, support, voting

I noticed that two of my questions received a number of upvotes today. At first, I thought perhaps they became active for some reason (edited, etc.) but I found out that neither of them had any recent activity. I mean, don't get me wrong; I'm not complaining; I just don't understand why they would receive those sudden upvotes.

- The first question was last active **24 days** ago. It just received **3 new upvotes** (+27%).
- The second question was last active **5 days** ago. It received **10 new upvotes** (+333%).

What's even more strange is that, because of Winter Bash, the home page is filled with posts about hats. So, I would expect the other/older posts to have less attention than usual.

Has anyone else experienced something similar? Is there a reason for those sudden upvotes? Maybe some people have extra free time because of the holiday season so they're checking older posts? Or am I just overthinking this?

Comment: They might've been shared somewhere (chat, perhaps)? But unless the culprit steps forward, you'll never know ;)

Comment: It's probably people hunting for hats.  This period has a knack of bumping up votes, flags, edits on old questions/answers.  I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both questions:

- [Please allow users without the close/reopen votes privilege to see the full details of close reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356902/295232)
- [Allow users to view the exact date and time they followed a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357687/295232)

are [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)s; it might be that users are hunting for hats, in particular [I wish to subscribe](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/i-wish-to-subscribe):

> Upvote 3 questions with the [feature-request] tag on Meta Stack Exchange

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I should probably hurry up and turn this post into a [feature-request] too then :-P